# Pyspark: Applying reduce by key to the values of an rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, reduce

After some transformations I have ended up with an rdd with the following format:

```py
[(0, [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 1), ('b', 1)])

(1, [('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('h', 1), ('h', 1)])]
```

I can't figure out how to essentially "reduceByKey()" on the values portion of this rdd.

This is what I'd like to achieve:

```py
[(0, [('a', 1), ('b', 3)])

(1, [('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('h', 2)])]
```

I was originally using .values() then applying reduceByKey to the result of that but then I end up losing my original key (in this case 0 or 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose the original key because `.values()` will only get value of the `key-value` in a row. You should sum the tuple in the row.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def sum_row(row):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for key, val in row[1]:
        result[key] += val
    return (row[0],list(result.items()))

data_rdd = data_rdd.map(sum_row)
print(data_rdd.collect())

# [(0, [('a', 1), ('b', 3)]), (1, [('h', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `values` gives RDD, `reduceByKey` works on all the values on RDD not row-wise.

You can also use `groupby`(ordering is required) to achieve the same:

```
from itertools import groupby

distdata.map(lambda x: (x[0], [(a, sum(c[1]  for c in b)) for a,b in groupby(sorted(x[1]), key=lambda p: p[0]) ])).collect()
```